# How to load an JPEG XR image file in Python

Tags: python, python-imageio, jpeg-xr

I have some images in the JPEG XR format (file endings ".wdp" & ".jxr") and want to load them in Python. I had to do quite some research since the format seems to be rather"exotic".

I finally found some clues that ImageIo seems to have support for the format (although just through another library but anyway) - It even got suggested here - [How to decode JPEG XR files in memory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038280/how-to-decode-jpeg-xr-files-in-memory-using-python)

I set up everything and tred to use the following code:

```
import imageio  

imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()
im = imageio.imread("FILE_NAME.jxr", format="JXR");
```

However it fails with the following error:

> ValueError: Could not load bitmap
>   "D:\SOME_DIRECTORIES_TO_FOLLOW...............\d02123020.jxr":
>   No known reason.

After further research my hopes got crushed when I found a bug report which presumably never got fixed -- https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/269

So it seems ImageIo is a dead end and I would like to know: Are other there other python libraries/etc that support the JPEG XR format?

Comment: Try `im = imagecodecs.imread('FILE_NAME.jxr')`.